# Why does this program output 8?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, ternary-operator, preprocessor-directive

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define abs(x) x > 0 ? x : -x

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", abs(abs(3 - 5)));
  return 0;
}
```

Why does the program above output 8 and not 2 while the program below outputs 2?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int abs(int x) {
  return x > 0 ? x : -x;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", abs(abs(3 - 5)));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `#define abs(x) x > 0 ? x : -x` to `#define abs(x) ((x) > 0 ? (x) : -(x))`

Comment: The program [outputs negative 8](http://ideone.com/H434lj), not 8.

Comment: I have recently noticed that I posted the code I changed, if expression was `#define abs(x) (x > 0 ? x : -x)` then it would [output positive eight](http://ideone.com/7WY5Ie), @dasblinkenlight, thanks by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is "because a macro is not a function".

Long answer is that macro parameters are expanded into the text of the program, so C compiler sees this long expression:

```
3 - 5 > 0 ? 3 - 5 : -3 - 5 > 0 ? 3 - 5 > 0 ? 3 - 5 : -3 - 5 : -3 - 5 > 0 ? 3 - 5 : -3 - 5
```

In the expansion, negative sign applies to `3`, not to `(3-5)`, yielding negative 8.

Although you can work around this issue by placing parentheses around `x` in the macro definition, defining an inline function would be a better choice.